Problem with torch.distributed Hanging Across Different Nodes Using NCCL
I'm trying to run a simple example using PyTorch's distributed package to send a tensor from one process to another using point-to-point (P2P) communication. However, the code hangs during the initialization of the process group
I have two different nodes with distinct IP addresses.
First, I ensured that the sender could ping the receiver successfully:
ping 34.123.202.88
PING 34.123.202.88 (34.123.202.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 34.123.202.88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=1.25 ms
64 bytes from 34.123.202.88: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=0.438 ms

I was also able to establish tcp connection over port 6001 using nc
After verifying connectivity, I ran the following scripts on each node with export NCCL_DEBUG=INFO However, the process hangs during execution.
Sender Node script:
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

# Replace with the IP address of Node 2
MASTER_ADDR = "localhost"
MASTER_PORT = 6001

dist.init_process_group(
    backend="nccl",
    init_method="tcp://{}:{}".format(MASTER_ADDR, MASTER_PORT),
    rank=0,
    world_size=2,
)

# Send a tensor to Node 2
print("Preparing to send tensor...")
tensor_to_send = torch.ones(5)
dist.send(tensor_to_send, dst=0)
print("Rank 0 sent tensor:", tensor_to_send)

dist.destroy_process_group()

Receiver Node script:
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

MASTER_ADDR = "34.123.202.88"
MASTER_PORT = 6001

dist.init_process_group(
    backend="nccl",
    init_method="tcp://{}:{}".format(MASTER_ADDR, MASTER_PORT),
    rank=1,
    world_size=2
)

print("Going to receive tensor...")
tensor_to_rcv = torch.zeros(5)
dist.recv(tensor=tensor_to_rcv, src=0)
print("Rank 1 received tensor:", tensor_to_rcv)

dist.destroy_process_group()

The PyTorch version I'm using is: :
torch 2.3.1+cu121
Any insights on why the process hangs and how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
